# Colorful dropdown menu in tkinter

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, colors, dropdown, optionmenu

Is it possible to add colorful items in dropdown in Tkinter? Dropdown will take its values from enum class. For example, enum class has 'red,yellow,green' elements. Sections of dropdown will be green, red, yellow colors according to element. How can i make that?

Comment: have you read through the documentation and tried it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Adding colors to the menu is possible with the keywords foreground and background; take a look.

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except:
    import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

menubar = tk.Menu(root)

filemenu = tk.Menu(menubar,tearoff=0)

filemenu.add_command(label="text 1")
filemenu.add_command(label='text 2', foreground = 'blue')
filemenu.add_command(label='text 3',background='green')

# entire dropdown menu has been given this color
editmenu = tk.Menu(menubar,tearoff=0,foreground = 'green')
editmenu.add_command(label='copy')
editmenu.add_command(label='paste')

menubar.add_cascade(menu=filemenu, label="File")
menubar.add_cascade(menu=editmenu, label="edit")

root.config(menu=menubar)

root.mainloop()
```

Taking colors from a predefined list, involves a for-loop.

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except:
    import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

menubar = tk.Menu(root,foreground='red')
filemenu = tk.Menu(menubar,tearoff=0)

text = ['text 1', 'text 2', 'text 3']
color = ['green','red','yellow']

for a,b in zip(text,color):
    filemenu.add_command(label=a,foreground=b)

menubar.add_cascade(menu=filemenu, label="File")
root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

EDIT: hopefully converted code to 2.7.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! I was trying since quite few hours. Is it possible to do it in a dropdown menu which i want to add to a grid and read the value for such a dropdown(the value can be the text or the color). Any hints?

Comment: not sure what you mean? isn't that sort of what I was doing with the `for`-loop (2nd example)?

Comment: No, here the colorful items are a part of filemenu. I need it to be a part of a separate dropdown widget which needs to be packed in a grid.

Comment: @user2694330 ah ok, you don't wish it to be a menu, but rather something like a [`combobox`](http://www.tkdocs.com/widgets/combobox.html) from tkk. If I recall correctly, `Combobox` doesn't offer that possibility. I saw somewhere a suggestion that this could be created by using a [`Listbox`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm), to which dropdown-capabilities were added. But can't you help further than the suggestion of googling it, and hope somebody created already created such a widget. ( if you find it, please return and post your findings  ^_^ )

Comment: I have been googling since a past few days but no luck :( Will update if i find something useful. Thanks for your input though! Appreciate it :D