# Is there a way to change the selected font color in a Tkinter menu?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-menu

Is there any way to change the selected font color of a menu item in Tkinter? I assumed it was selectcolor but I haven't been able to get that to do anything. Help would be much appreciated.

I would like to have the "Save" text stay black when I hover the cursor over it. I'm just using effbot.org's sample code for now:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def hello():
    print("hello!")

menubar = Menu(root)

# create a pulldown menu, and add it to the menu bar
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="Open", command=hello)
filemenu.add_command(label="Save", command=hello)
filemenu.add_separator()
filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

# create more pulldown menus
editmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
editmenu.add_command(label="Cut", command=hello)
editmenu.add_command(label="Copy", command=hello)
editmenu.add_command(label="Paste", command=hello)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=editmenu)

helpmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
helpmenu.add_command(label="About", command=hello)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpmenu)

# display the menu
root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Relevant [colorful-dropdown-menu-in-tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43238067) a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are `activebackground` and `activeforeground` options using which you can change the background and foreground color on Hover.

Replace this

```
filemenu.add_command(label="Save", command=hello)
```

with this

```
filemenu.add_command(label="Save", command=hello, activeforeground = 'black')
```

Hope this works as expected :)